# Does $(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax})^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax}) = \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{AAx}-2\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{Ay}+\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{y}$

Tags: matrices

I am told, that if $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric $\mathbf{A}^T=\mathbf{A}$ and:

$$ (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax})^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax}) = \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{AAx}-2\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{Ay}+\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{y}$$

But I do not understand.  I get:

$$ (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax})^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Ax}) = \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{AAx}-\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{Ax}-\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{Ay}+\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{y}$$

What am I missing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $y^TAx$ = $1\times n$ times $n\times n$ times $n\times 1$, so a $1\times 1$ matrix. Thus $y^TAx = (y^TAx)^T = x^TA^Ty = x^TAy$.